# Getting cannot access permission denied error

Tags: linux, permissions, ls

[image]I am getting question marks [?] in the "ls -lrth" output for files. When I try to change permission it gives "cannot access 'filename'" permission denied error.[image]

[image: H.png]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text; just paste the text.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the root directory of a Windows system disk, which uses a NTFS filesystem.

Normally, the question marks in the `ls -l` listing would indicate that you currently have only *read* (`r`) permission to the directory (here `/mnt/c`), but not the corresponding *access* (`x` for directories) permission. But that would happen to all files and sub-directories in that case, so something else must be going on.

(If you want to check the ownership and permissions of `/mnt/c`, run `ls -l /mnt` or `ls -ld /mnt/c`.)

Since NTFS has a complex system of Access Control Lists (ACLs) which can act essentially as a superset of classic Unix-style permissions, I would guess that those files are probably owned by the SYSTEM user of Windows and have an ACL on them that prevents you from even seeing the detailed information on them.

This also explains why you cannot `chmod` the file `swapfile.sys`: in order to be able to `chmod` something in a Unix-style filesystem, you must either be *the owner of the file* or *have administrator access*. Since you are apparently using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), the `root` account of WSL is only the admin of the WSL subsystem, not of the whole underlying Windows host.